# How to shutdown the entire system after certain time period?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, boost

**Background**

I have [TPS61240](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61240.pdf) Boost converter module. In my system, TPS61240 is used to convert 3V DC to 5V DC. This 5V supply is then used to power whole system. Moreover micro controller driven system (Atmega16).

**Requirement**

I want to turn off the whole system, lets say like 1 minute after the start-up. TPS61240 has ENABLE pin. If supplied high logic to ENABLE pin, boost converter produces the output voltage of 5v. All I want to do is make micro controller to control this ENABLE pin.

**Problem**

If I connect the Enable pin to micro controller pin, Then at first how do I power the System.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The circuit below should bootstrap the controller in the manner you describe. When the circuit first turns on and 3V is applied, a pulse of 3V will pass through C1, which should be enough to start the boost converter and produce 5V at the output. Once this has happened, R1 weakly pulls up the EN signal to the 5V output which now exists (magic!).

Since the Atmega16's outputs default to high impedance (check the datasheet) it will be out of circuit effectively, and R2 limits any current from the initial bootstrap pulse possibly damaging the Atmega16 (as it is unpowered when the pulse occurs, which puts it outside of recommended absolute maximum ratings).

Once you are ready to shut down, simply set DIO as an output and write a digital LOW to it - this will disable the boost converter and when the Atmega16 shuts down there will no longer be any voltage on the EN pin (as there is nothing to provide it except C1, which is now charged and hence will not provide the pulse). In order to start the circuit again, you need to remove the 3V, wait a second or two and then reapply it.

[image: schematic]

Please note that the values are approximate (I used them to do this in the past with an MCP1640T) and you will need to check the TPS61240 datasheet to ensure that 3V on the EN pin will be enough to start it up.

Comment: I haven't worked on this before, is it perfectly safe this way? and is it the perfect way of doing this?

Comment: There is nothing inherently dangerous in this circuit - I'm not sure what you really mean by safe in this context. It certainly should not damage any of the components or otherwise risk creating a hazardous voltage or starting a fire due to overcurrent. But then that's largely due to the inherently low voltages and currents involved.

There is no such thing as a perfect circuit either! I like this one, and I use it a lot. But others may have other preferences. If we're lucky they may answer and you can compare approaches.